# Issue replicating PHP CURL request like browser

Tags: php, curl

I am having some issues with a browser request that I am trying to replicate with curl. I am currently working on a university project and am stuck.

I am trying to replicate a browser request to the following URL: http://vm.tiktok.com/e9VDx8/ When I visit the page in my browser I am redirected to a page with a video and some other content. When I try using CURL I am being shown a 404 page not found error. My curl request looks like the following.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $USER_AGENT);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  realpath('./cookies.txt') );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookies.txt') );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have looked at the headers from the original URL in the browser and tried to copy paste them into curl but still I get the 404 page. If I copy the browser request as a curl request from chrome developer tools and run it in terminal it works fine.

```
curl "http://vm.tiktok.com/e9VDx8/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-CA;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7" -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.213365735.1552156986; _gid=GA1.2.1717226934.1552319684; tt_webid=6667489497775638018" --compressed
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I figure this issue out minutes after posting for help. Earlier in my script I truncate the URL to make sure there's no invalid characters and such. While doing so I changed the URL to lower case which caused the issue since the URL's are case sensitive.